# Trouble with x-axis and error bars (line graph with two lines) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-deviation, linegraph

The data below: 
[image]

I am having trouble with my x-axis as its looses its order when i run the code. I am looking to get an axis that runs from 1 to 14 (levels ordered 1 t0 14). [image]

**Data summarised for R format:**

```
chlo <- data.frame(Culture=rep(c("Axenix", "Mixed"), each=14),
                   Time=rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"),2),
                   Growth=c(4246443, 5863739, 10599835, 19379643, 23071353, 26763062,   29143319,   30373889,   32800365,   34080042,   35359719,   36642284,   38629683,   39663824, 4238613,  3983333, 8383333, 11266667, 14600000,   17933333,   23400000,   25866667,   29333333,   32116667,   34900000,   42833333,   50200000,   54200000))

str(chlo)
```

Looking at the levels

```
chlo$Time
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 14 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I am also having trouble adding vertical standard deviation bars:

For the first 1 to 14 values (Axenic) the respective sd's are: (+ & -):

```
249116, 960902, 2712164,    991667, 914799, 843048, 1826696,    2050218, 3457363,   3664220,    3876349,    4410793, 5123502,   5193421
```

For the second set of values 1 to 14 (Mixed) values the respective sd's are (+ & -):

```
44621,  980221, 1871719,    332916, 326917, 321455, 4200000,    2013289,    2386071,    2559460,    3207803,    2773686,    2170253, 5102940
```

Answer (score 0):

`Time` is a continuous measure, and should be numeric:

```
chlo$Time<-as.numeric(chlo$Time)

# install.packages("ggplot2") #uncomment and run if you don't have this package
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(chlo,aes(x=Time,y=Growth, colour=Culture))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

The error bars question is a separate one and has been asked many times, search for the `geom_errorbars()` function.

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-error-bars-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization